# CloudFront Signed URLs access denied

Tags: php, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to add signed URLs to my videos on CloudFront everything set to be fine but when I open my URL it shows me the Access Denied error every time when I generate the URL code here is the following error

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>081DED49D4E126A6</RequestId>
<HostId>Lx+3mwxdCGo1vWAGM5RzPHDKrwEkvQwi8XiH2hBgj51XWsxu4gqY3Zr+w1x4ZoZQAYWEHV9u1wA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Here is my code I don't know what I am doing wrong in it

```
<?php
$urlShow = getSignedURL("http://d22bw8b4o37yyl.cloudfront.net/test/love1.mp4", 500);
function getSignedURL($resource, $timeout)
{
    //This comes from key pair you generated for cloudfront
    $keyPairId = "APKAIJP3H7LLN44FL2OQ";

    $expires = time() + $timeout; //Time out in seconds
    $json = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"'.$resource.'","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'.$expires.'}}}]}';     

    //Read Cloudfront Private Key Pair
    $fp=fopen("pk-APKAIJP3H7LLN44FL2OQ.pem","r"); 
    $priv_key=fread($fp,8192); 
    fclose($fp); 

    //Create the private key
    $key = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
    if(!$key)
    {
        echo "<p>Failed to load private key!</p>";
        return;
    }

    //Sign the policy with the private key
    if(!openssl_sign($json, $signed_policy, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1))
    {
        echo '<p>Failed to sign policy: '.openssl_error_string().'</p>';
        return;
    }

    //Create url safe signed policy
    $base64_signed_policy = base64_encode($signed_policy);
    $signature = str_replace(array('+','=','/'), array('-','_','~'), $base64_signed_policy);

    //Construct the URL
    $url = $resource.'?Expires='.$expires.'&Signature='.$signature.'&Key-Pair-Id='.$keyPairId;

    return $url;
}

echo $urlShow;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this because the time duration for expiry you have used in your code isn't proper. To resolve the issue, First we need to update the **Bucket** policy and use the proper **Key-Pair-ID** and **Private Key** then in line two of the code use proper Unix time-stamp like this `time() + 600` instead of `500` [PHP, time - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

Here is the full code that will resolve the issue

```
<?php
$urlShow = getSignedURL("http://d22bw8b4o37yyl.cloudfront.net/test/love1.mp4", time() + 600);
function getSignedURL($resource, $timeout) {
//This comes from key pair you generated for cloudfront
$keyPairId = "APKAIJP3H7LLN44FL2OQ";

$expires = time() + $timeout; //Time out in seconds
$json = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"'.$resource.'","Condition":{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":'.$expires.'}}}]}'; 

//Read Cloudfront Private Key Pair
$fp=fopen("pk-APKAIJP3H7LLN44FL2OQ.pem","r"); 
$priv_key=fread($fp,8192); 
fclose($fp); 

//Create the private key
$key = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
if(!$key) {
echo "<p>Failed to load private key!</p>";
return;
}

//Sign the policy with the private key
if(!openssl_sign($json, $signed_policy, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1)) {
echo '<p>Failed to sign policy: '.openssl_error_string().'</p>';
return;
}

//Create url safe signed policy
$base64_signed_policy = base64_encode($signed_policy);
$signature = str_replace(array('+','=','/'), array('-','_','~'), $base64_signed_policy);

//Construct the URL
$url = $resource.'?Expires='.$expires.'&Signature='.$signature.'&Key-Pair-Id='.$keyPairId;
return $url;
}

echo $urlShow;
?>
```